# Bounty community wiki?

Tags: discussion, bounty, community-wiki

I want to get an answer to our new [quantile regression community wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/622609/247274) that addresses a particular aspect of quantile regression that is not being addressed in the current answers, so I thought I’d throw a bounty its way.

Since all future answers will be community wiki, how would the bounty work? I would part with my $50$ or $100$ points no matter what, I figure, but who gets the points when ownership is communal?

Comment: See this related Meta Math.SE post: [Bounty on a "Community wiki" question - what will happen?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19282/bounty-on-a-community-wiki-question-what-will-happen)

Comment: And for the general discussion, see this Meta.SE post: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bounty should go to whomever you award it to.  If you don't award it on time, it should go to the answer that accrued the most upvotes during the bounty period.

**Update:**  [The earned reputation will go to the person who initiated the awarded answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19282/bounty-on-a-community-wiki-question-what-will-happen), even if others edited the answer subsequently to improve it.  You would not be able to award points to an editor, even if they added the bulk of the value.